# Ask for reference of a stochastic process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

I would like to know whether the following stochastic process is well studied.

Let $\{U_k: k \ge 1\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variable. $U_1$ is uniformly distributed on the unit interval $[0, 1]$. Now consider the stochastic process $(F(t))_{0<t<1}$, where

$$F(t)= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty 1_{U_k \le t^k}.$$

I would like to know the potentially existing literature on the above process. Does this process have a name ?

Any comment and reference is welcomed. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Wild guess: it's an inhomogeneous Poisson process, or a time-change of one.

Comment: It seems that by computing the joint characteristic function of  $F(t)$ and $F(t+s) - F(t)$, these two r.v.'s can not be independent.